# What is the equivalent function for REPLACE(of Oracle) in sybase

Tags: function, replace, sybase

What is the equivalent function for REPLACE(of Oracle) in sybase?

Comment: Put the question in the text, and make a real title...

Answer (score 3):

I think that it's the [str_replace](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks213.htm) function that you want.

As far as I can tell it's not an exact equivalent, as the third parameter is not optional, but the general usage is the same.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the Sybase Replace function?

http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-iq/iqg1250e/iqref/@Generic__BookTextView/37946;pt=37863

Syntax:

REPLACE ( original-string, search-string, replace-string )

Example:
SELECT REPLACE( 'abc.def.abc.ghi', 'abc', 'xx' ) FROM iq_dummy